# REGEX: Find block of text that starts with WORDX, ends with WORDZ, and does not contain WORDY

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been trying to perform a search on Notepad++ which finds a block of text that starts with a certain string (StringX) and ends with another one (StringZ) but does not contain another one (StringY) anywhere in between. 
To give you some context I'm looking in a file that contains thousands of blocks that repeat the above explained pattern and only a couple don't have it.

Edit 2:
The specific example has been uploaded to https://justpaste.it/1668j

The REGEX needs to find the string **chargingContextSpecific** `.+?chargingContextSpecific((.|\r)+?)` and after that go to the next iteration of 3 consecutive closing curly  brackets **}** `\}\r.+?\}\r.+?\}` and validate that in between these two strings the text **JKLMN = 3GPP-Charging-Id** is NOT present. In the example Block# 0 and Block# 2 are expected outputs and Block# 1 contains the pattern I'm looking for.

Please notice that the file I'm searching in consists of 2million+ lines and there are only 6 or 7 cases where the condition will match.

Comment: can you add actual string of 2 examples one with StringY and one without. and what are you trying to extract.

Comment: I think `(?s)StringX(?:(?!StringY|StringX).)*?StringZ` will work.

Comment: I updated the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your example:

```
[#0-9\s:]+chargingContextSpecific((?!JKLMN[\s=]*3GPP-Charging-Id).)*?(\s*:\s*\}\s*){3}
```

You need to tick "Matches newlines" in the search box. This should do it. I've tried it and it returned only 1 match from the string that you've provided.

Comment: @JoseLuisGochiContreras - try the updated regex, it's a bit slow though. I'd just write a script to read the document and loop through all lines instead.

Comment: I think I did not explain properly. The example I show is not an extract from the actual document I'm using (I cannot add the actual text because it contains customer confidential data), but I need a regular expression that searches every line until it finds StringX `.+StringX`, after that it must select all text that follows StringX until it finds StringZ which is three consecutive '}' `\}\r.+\}\r.+\}` and all this should happen every time that StringY is NOT present in between. Any random combination of characters can be present in the whole block of text.

Comment: @JoseLuisGochiContreras - you can alter the info and re-post it here. the regex I added works on your current sample. if you need more help you have to add an actual example

Comment: I'll re-edit the example and remove the comments so that only the actual text I need to filter appears, however I still need a regular expression that does not match the exact text I post but rather the general pattern, e.g. instead of matching the exact amount of spaces prior to StringX, an expression like `.+` that can catch anything from the start of the line until it finds StringX, this because the document can vary between blocks of text and the only constants would be StringX, StringY, and the three consecutive '}' characters (StringZ)

Comment: @JoseLuisGochiContreras - with the sample you put in your post is vague that's why you need to put actual data you want to extract without any comments or extra strings

Comment: That's precisely my point. I don't need to care if there's any strings in between the ones that matter to me. In my actual file the blocks have a somewhat random behavior and no block of text is identical to any other. That is why I try to explain that I need a general expression that can work with any random strings in between the ones I can work with

Comment: it doesn't matter, you have added comments and manipulated the sample. you need to provide the original sample otherwise I can't help you. Regex can be unpredictable if you add extra strings.

Comment: I've updated the quiestion with an specific example taken from the original file.

Comment: Your answer is working on the format that the web page is giving to the text, unfortunately it does not with my original File, I'll try and figure out the logic behind it to make it match my actual file and will be back to you ASAP. Thanks a lot for your effort and attention to this topic so far.

Comment: @JoseLuisGochiContreras - you're welcome, probably minor changes could make it work. again I'm working on what you're providing me. I think you'll figure it out as it's not that hard.. anyways please do mark the answer as accepted and if you need more help let me know